# check string with regular expressions for some value

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I search the variable `$message` using preg_match to find the text `[sh 2000]`

The variable $message is sent from a web service.

I want to know if `[sh 2000]` was submitted as `[sh 2000]` So I want to ignore the existence of a space between `sh` and `2000`. 
AND PUT `SH` in array [0] and `#NUMBBER` in array[1];

before for ([ONLYNUMBER] LIKE [2] ) i used :

```
preg_match("/\[(\p{N}*)\]/", $message, $find)
```

any help ? 
thanks

Comment: Why do you use the unicode class `\p{N}`? Do you need to deal with other digits than `[0-9]`?

Comment: yes i need digits too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ php -r '$message = "[sh 2000]"; preg_match("/\[(\w+)\s*(\p{N}+)\]/", $message, $find); print_r($find);'
Array
(
    [0] => [sh 2000]
    [1] => sh
    [2] => 2000
)
```

or :

```
$ php -r '$message = "[sh 2000]"; preg_match("/\[(\w+)\s*(\p{N}+)\]/", $message, $find); unset($find[0]); print_r($find);'
Array
(
    [1] => sh
    [2] => 2000
)
```

Comment: i want put sh in array [0] and number in array [1]

Comment: !? Is it not enough ? This is what you have in the first snippet with key 0 if you have message like `$message = "[shi 2000]";`

Comment: i need sh + shi + shp ! and when messeage [sh 2000] array [1] sh array [2] 2000 ! 
and when [shi 2000] array [1] shi array [2] 2000
and when [shp 2000] array [1] shp array [2] 2000 !!! 
is it possible ? 
thank you for help